# How would I split the results into two columns

Tags: php

How would I split the results into two columns?

```
        foreach($subjects AS $subject){
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"subjects[]\" value=\"".$subject['subject']."\">\x20".$subject['subject']."<br \>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work though I havent testested it:

#### PHP:

```
<?php

$inputs = '<ul class="checkbox-columns">';

foreach($subjects as $subject){
    $inputs .= '<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="subjects[]" value="' . $subject['subject'] . '"/>' . $subject['subject'] . '</label></li>';
}

$inputs .= '</ul>';

echo $inputs;
```

#### CSS:

```
.checkbox-columns {
    width: 200px;
}
.checkbox-columns li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This creates a variable called `$inputs` containing a string with an opening `<ul>` tag with a CSS class of `.checkbox-columns`. It then loops over an array of `$subjects` and appends a string of list items (`<li>`) containing the inputs (with it's value attribute and label text set to the value of `$subject['subject']`) to the `$inputs` variable. Finally, when the loop is finished it appends a closing `</ul>` tag and `echo`s out the string of HTML that was built.

Then you can style the output with some CSS as needed.

#### A few notes on the code you posted:

- Instead of only using double quotes (e.g `"`), it's a bit easier to read if you alternate between single and double quotes (e.g `"` and `'`). There is also no need to escape the HTML attribute's quotes this way.
- In the `foreach` parameters, `AS` should be lowercase.
- I wrapped the whole `<input />` tag in a `<label>` tag. This lets you add the label text inside HTML instead of just dumping it into a random text node.
- Depending on where the `$subjects` array comes from you should strongly consider [Sanitizing the output](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).